# how to call a multiple function within a multiple one by mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have defined a multiple function before and i want to call it within another multiple function by Mathematica software.

[image]

Comment: Functions are first-class in WL.  Use the function *name* as an argument.  (You are also missing the upper limit of the integral.)

Comment: i am thankful for you very much

Comment: but what about this one f[a_,b_] := a+b*a^2 g[c_,d_] :=(c/d)+d*5 and i want to call both of them in other one with values for example h[x_,y_] := x[a,b] +y[c,d] in other world how can i call the functions with values simultaneously

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must decide what is known ahead of time and what is known only
when the function `h` is called.  For example, you propose

```
    f[a_,b_] := a+b*a^2
    g[c_,d_] := (c/d)+d*5
    h[x_,y_] := x[a,b] +y[c,d]
```

This only makes sens if `{a,b,c,d}` are known outside of the functions.
That may simply be the opposite of what you want.
That is, you may want to define `h` in terms of known functions
but unknown parameter values.  E.g.,

```
    f[a_,b_] := a+b*a^2
    g[c_,d_] := (c/d)+d*5
    h[a_,b_,c_,d_] := f[a,b] +g[c,d]
```

Finally, you may want to define `h` in terms of unknown functions
as well as unknown parameter values.  E.g.,

```
    h[a_,b_,c_,d_,f1_,f2_] := f1[a,b] + f2[c,d]
```

Comment: nobody can Measures my happiness  thank you very much my bro :)

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the function name as an argument.

```
f[a_, b_] := a*b;
g[c_, d_, e_] := c*e[c, d];

g[3, 5, f]
(* 45 *)
```

Comment: but what about this one       f[a_,b_] := a+b*a^2          g[c_,d_] :=(c/d)+d*5         and i want to call both of them in other one  with values for example                 h[x_,y_] := x[a,b] +y[c,d]   in other world how can i call the functions with values simultaneously